# Deployment issue - standard TASK field missing

Tags: deployment, tasks

I am getting the following error when I deploy a page layout containing the related list of open activities.

```
Invalid field:TASK.SUBJECT in related list:RelatedActivityList
```

Now to get the deployment to pass, I needed to remove the XML part of the page layout that contains details for this related list. Why is this happening, isn't this a reference to a standard field? Any thoughts guys.

Comment: Just guessing may be current user dont have access to that field. Can you goto that field and check the security for  current user profile ?

Comment: If you are talking about the user that does deployment, that is the sys admin. So he has access

Comment: For what it's worth, I was just able to deploy a page layout to the Account object with a RelatedActivityList that contained the TASK.SUBJECT field.

Comment: My custom object already had `<enableActivities>true</enableActivities>` but like the answer from George S suggests, I had to toggle this false (push) then true again (push) before my layout would push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this a bug - there is a VERY similar issue with a different related list [Invalid field:SOLUTION.ISSUE in related list:RelatedSolutionList Error when deploying Case Page Layouts](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YNVAA2) .

Since the issue is so similar and was so recently fixed, I think you should report this one as a bug.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I have ran into this issue being some what more popular than mine - while googling the error. Thanks Caspar

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was deploying a Custom Object with

`<enableActivities>true</enableActivities>`

omitted, and then redeploying with the layout and enableActivities set.

That should have worked, but failed due to this bug: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IXGkQAO&title=excluding-enableactivities-and-enablereports-settings-from-customobject-metadata-incorrectly-disables-the-settings-in-target-org

Adding enableActivities to the original deployment fixed it.

Comment: Between the accepted answer and this add'l answer I was able to get my source deployed for api 53 (winter 22)